# How to generate data for News Feed efficiently like facebook , googleplus , twitter e.t.c?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam, database-recommendation

I have created table as

```
      post (
            post_id int(15) auto_increment  primary key ,
            user_id  int(11) ,
            post_text varchar(2000) , 
            post_type int(1),
            attachment int(1)
         ) ;

  Comment (
            comment_id primary key auto_increment ,
            post_id int(11) , 
            user_id int(11),
            comment_text varchar(2000)
         ) ;
```

and i have three more table to get posts for **USER** as

```
friend (id int(11) primary key auto_increment ,user_id int(11) ,friend_id int(11) ) ;
group  (id int(11) primary key auto_increment ,user_id int(11) ,group_id int(11)  ) ;
like   (id int(11) primary key auto_increment ,user_id int(11) ,page_id int(11)   ) ;
```

I used three table to minimize no of rows in table .

News feed for User **"a"**

```
$posts = 
    select * from post
    where user_id in 
    (
       select f_id  from (
                 (select friend_id as f_id from friend  where user_id = 'a') 
               union 
                 (select group_id as f_id  from group  where user_id = 'a') 
               union
                 (select page_id as f_id   where user_id = 'a'  )
                         )
    )  
    order by post_id ,
    limit $start   $end ;
```

Above query returns maximum 30 posts for user 'a'  ;

### Query for Comment

```
 foreach($posts as $row){
    $comments[$index]  = 
    mysql_query(
          "select * from comment 
          where post_id = $row->post_id 
          order by comment_id 
          limit 0 10 ; "
               );
    $index++;
  }
```

My problem is How to make it efficient ?

Assume No. of tupples in table as
case 1 : `1 million` in post table  and `100 millions` in comment table .
case 2 : `10,000` in post table  and `1,00,000` in comment table .

Query is done frequently like social Network site .
Using **APACHE** server , **PHP** server side scripting , **MYSQL** Database .

If it can't be made more efficient than comment .